# Imported as maven project and none of the folders are source folders

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have an assignment where I have to import a maven project and create a test case class to test certain methods from the project. The problem is that when I import the maven project into my eclipse workspace, none of the folders appear as source folders (instead they just show up as regular folders). This is problematic because the new test class I created does not recognize any class that I want to test because the folder type is not set as a "source folder" for the imported classes. For example, I would like to test the "Repeat" class from my imported maven project, but I cannot do this because when I try to instantiate a "Repeat" object, I get an error saying "Repeat cannot be resolved as a type". I have tried configuring the project facets, cleaned the project, and did a maven update project. I am not sure what to do now. The maven project has over 100 classes so I cannot simply create a new source folder and drag over the classes.

Comment: you can classify the existing folders as "source folders" manually

Comment: do you have another existing Maven project in your Eclipse workspace? Does the Maven integration in Eclipse work proper in this project?